# Bunch-Davies initial condition

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, vacuum, cosmological-inflation

I have the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation in terms of $Q(t)$

\begin{align*}
Q''(t)+3HQ'(t)+k^2Q/a^2+\left(3\phi'(t)^2-\phi'(t)^4/2H^2+2\phi'(t)V_\phi/H+V_{\phi\phi}\right)Q=0,\ u=aQ
\end{align*}

and also the initial condition from Bunch-Davies

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k>>aH}u_k(\tau)=\frac{e^{-ik\tau}}{\sqrt{2k}}
\end{align*}

How do you calculate the solution from this point? I know that $k$ is the pivot scale where I am calculating the curvature perturbation, but my doubt is that if I have to use this initial condition as a functional, or if I have to get a numerical value knowing that $\tau$ can only take values from $k=aH$ to $aH\rightarrow0$. For example, take when $\tau\rightarrow-\infty$, or when is it an appropriate time to take the initial condition? I am asking this since when I plot the initial condition, it highly oscillates until the mode gets out of the Hubble horizon.  I'm working with the Starobinsky model

\begin{align*}
V(\phi)=3/4\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{2/3}\phi(t)}\right)^2
\end{align*}

Equations with $c=h=G=M_P=1$.